# Removing empty items from a JList

Tags: java, string, jlist, spaces

I have coded a simply to do list program which adds text the user inputs through a JInputDialog (for example: "go grocery shopping") to a JList. The program is running fine, but I thought I would try to prevent the user from pressing okay in the dialog box without entering text, or just entering spaces, through the following code:

```
        //if create button is pressed
    }else if(src == create){
        //show an input dialog box
        String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "What do you want to remember?");

        /*f the length of the given string is zero, or if the length of the string without spaces
        is zero, then tell the user*/
            if(s.length() == 0 || removeSpaces(s).length() == 0){   
                System.out.println("Nothing has been entered");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You must enter a text value!");

            //if the string is valid, add it to the file
            }else{
                sfile.add(s);
                System.out.println("Item added to list. " + s.length());
            }

        }else if(src == close){
            System.exit(0);
        }
}

    //remove all white spaces and tabs from the string
    public String removeSpaces(String s){
        s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        return s;  
    }
}
```

This code works and shows the "Nothing has been entered" dialog when the user has not entered anything whatsoever, but does not work when the user enters spaces. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about using s.trim() to remove the white space instead?

Comment: `s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");` doesn't affect `s` since strings are immutable, but returns new string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use s.trim() instead of your removeSpaces method?

```
} else if (src == create) {
    //show an input dialog box
    String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "What do you want to remember?");

    /*f the length of the given string is zero, or if the length of the string without spaces
        is zero, then tell the user*/
    if (s.trim.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Nothing has been entered");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You must enter a text value!");
        //if the string is valid, add it to the file
    } else {
        sfile.add(s);
        System.out.println("Item added to list. " + s.length());
    }

} else if (src == close) {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

or you could change your remove spaces method to: (as Pshemo mentioned)

```
public String removeSpaces(String s){
    return s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
}
```